# What is an alternative to php function bcpow?

Tags: php

I'm using this guide - http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/

to generate short codes for URL.

But bcpow() isn't working anyhow on my system.

I'm using php-cli and phpinfo(); shows bcmath is installed.

Numeric to shortcode -

```
function aplhaIdCalc( $in ) {
    $index = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";        
    $base = 62;
    $out = "";
    for ($t = floor(log($in, $base)); $t >= 0; $t--) {
      $bcp = bcpow($base, $t);
      $a   = floor($in / $bcp) % $base;
      $out = $out . substr($index, $a, 1);
      $in  = $in - ($a * $bcp);
    }
    $out = strrev($out); // reverse
    return $out;
}
```

Shortcode to numeric -

```
function idAlphaCalc( $in ) {
    $index = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";        
    $base = 62;
    $in  = strrev($in);
    $out = 0;
    $len = strlen($in) - 1;
    for ($t = 0; $t <= $len; $t++) {
      $bcpow = bcpow($base, $len - $t);
      $out   = $out + strpos($index, substr($in, $t, 1)) * $bcpow;
    }
    $out = sprintf('%F', $out);
    $out = substr($out, 0, strpos($out, '.'));
    return $out;
}
```

How can I use these functions without bcpow and yet get similar output and input?

I can't understand these BCMath functions but I think base_convert might work.

Edit : Changing `bcpow` to `pow` works. What are the risks involved in using `pow` ?

Comment: AFAIK there are no risks involved... Only thing that might happen is that big numbers might be formatted in scientific notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diference between Math-Functions and BC Math-Functions:

- [Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.math.php): These math functions will only
  handle values within the range of the
  integer and float types on your
  computer
- [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php): For arbitrary precision
  mathematics PHP offers the Binary
  Calculator which supports numbers of
  any size and precision, represented
  as strings.

So **precision** is the answer.

Sure `bcmath` is loaded? Testet your functions on my local environment. no problem at all.

And you got a typo in your first function `aplhaIdCalc` => `alphaIdCalc`

Answer (score 0):

Should the bcmath extension be non-functional, then you could resort to exec:

```
$pow = `echo '135^71' | bc`;
```

Take care to escapeshellcmd the numbers anyway. However this is a pretty slow workaround if done in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using wrong php path. The one with bcmath installed was /usr/local/lib/php and I was using /usr/bin/php in shebang.